# Clone specific attributes of array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

i need some help with cloning attributes of hashes.
I have arrays `A`,`B` of X number of hashes (currently 2):

```
A = [
  {"v1"=>{"description"=>"abc", "export_value"=>"2"}},
  {"v2"=>{"description"=>"cba", "export_value"=>"2"}}
]

B = [ 
  {"v1"=>{"description"=>"", "export_value"=>"3"}},
  {"v2"=>{"description"=>"", "export_value"=>"5"}}
]
```

Is there any way (some function or anything) in Ruby that can clone certain attributes from one hash to another.

For example i would like to clone "export_values" attribute from array `B` to `A` so final array of hashes would look like:

```
C = [
  {"v1"=>{"description"=>"abc", "export_value"=>"3"}},
  {"v2"=>{"description"=>"cba", "export_value"=>"5"}}
]
```

Comment: Are arrays `A,B` certain and guaranteed to have the same number of elements always? If they do not, what value should be used? Would it remain the original `export_value` from `A` or become `nil`?

Comment: Arrays have same number of elements and same attributes just values for hash keys are different @MichaelBerkowski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
A.map.with_index do |h, i| 
    h.merge(B[i]) do |_, hash_from_A, hash_from_B| 
        hash_from_A.merge(hash_from_B) do |k, o, n|
            k == "export_value" ? n : o
        end
    end
end

#=> [{"v1"=>{"description"=>"abc", "export_value"=>"3"}},
#    {"v2"=>{"description"=>"cba", "export_value"=>"5"}}]
```

---

If your app has access to Rails Active Support gem, then, you could simplify above code just a bit by using `Hash#deep_merge`.

```
require "active_support/core_ext/hash"

A.map.with_index do |h, i| 
    h.deep_merge(B[i]) do |k, o, n|
        k == "export_value" ? n : o
    end
end
```

Comment: Yes i do use rails. Thank you, this helped! Could you explain me what are "k", "o", "n"? I'm trying to type validation if all other attributes are not sameto return false so no merging. Only "export_value" can be different in "A" and "B" hashes. So please explain if you can, thanks!

Comment: When merging two hashes, block is called if a key is present in both hashes so that you can decide how to resolve the new value for that key.  Parameters to block are key, old value and new value.  "old value" is value of key in hash on which merge is called, "new value" is value of key in hash that is passed as argument to merge method. http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge